# DmCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec runs, but can't add other code

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I am using an Access form for data entry. When the user gets to the end they have two command button options. 1) Add From Same Capture, and 2) Add from Different Capture. If the user wants to enter data from the same capture they click the command button. I envision some VBA code to do the following:
1) Add the record to the underlying table
2) Clear the form so it is ready for the new data.
3) Auto fill several fields from the previous record.
4) Go to the top of the form.

So far I've only been able to get the *DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec* to work.

When I use this code I receive a "Run-time error '2105': You can't go to the specified record"

```
Sub cmdSameCap_Click()
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    DoCmd.GoToControl CapDate
End Sub
```

I figure I can't have commands below the .GoToRecord, but when I convert a macro (which does this same thing) it shows that the .GoToControl is underneath the .GoToRecord. When I copy paste or use the VBA conversion and attempt to add the autofill code I get the same error.

Any suggestions,
Thank you!

Mitch

Comment: Assuming CapDate is a control that you can go to, then try "Me.CapDate.SetFocus'.  Is your form controls bound or unbound? I assume you have code to save the values from the current record BEFORE you try to add a new one?

Comment: The form controls are bound to an underlying table (I think that is what you mean). I am still receiving the same error with 'Me.CapDate.SetFocus'. However, I have noticed that the data from the form is added to the underlying table, it just wont advance to the next record, with the same run time error.

Comment: Placing the '.SetFocus' before the '.GoToRecord' works. I will keep it like this unless there is a better option. Now I must move on to the autofill portion. Any pointers there.

Comment: Save old values in either form current event or before update. Then after . add new populate with saved data. I assume user can view record but make no changes or change record before adding new?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue as Wayne suggested.

I saved the values on the current form as a variable. Then used:

```
Me.CapDate.SetFocus
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```

To move to the next record. I then set the values for the new record equal to the variables I declared. Works like a champ!